# Mongodb aggregation - count arrays with elements having integer value greater than

Tags: mongodb

I need to write a MongoDB aggregation pipeline to count the objects having arrays containing two type of values:

- >=10
- >=20

#### This is my dataset:

```
[
 { values: [ 1, 2, 3] },
 { values: [12, 1, 3] },
 { values: [1, 21, 3] },
 { values: [1, 2, 29] },
 { values: [22, 9, 2] }
]
```

#### This would be the expected output

```
{
  has10s: 4,
  has20s: 3
}
```

Mongo's [$in (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) seems to be the tool for the job, except I can't get it to work.

#### This is my (non working) pipeline:

```
db.mytable.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "has10s" : { 
         "$in": [ { "$gte" : [10, "$$CURRENT"]}, "$values"]} 
    },
     "has20s" : { 
         "$in": [ { "$gte" : [20, "$$CURRENT"]}, "$values"]} 
    }
  },
  { $group: { ... sum ... } }
])
```

The output of $in seems to be always true. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      has10: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$values",
            as: "item",
            cond: { $gte: [ "$$item", 10 ] }
          }
        }
      },
      has20: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$values",
            as: "item",
            cond: { $gte: [ "$$item", 20 ] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: 1,
      has10: { $sum: "$has10" },
      has20: { $sum: "$has20" }
    }
  }
])
```

Using `$project` with `$filter` to get the actual elements and then via `$size` to get the array length.

See it [working here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cKWuHL1nx6Y)

Comment: I was afraid this was going to be the answer :(
I'll wait and see if anyone has any more declarative solution, otherwise I'll accept your. For not, thanks! :)